# X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName not finding my certificate?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, x509certificate2

I am making a self-signed X509 certificate as follows:

```
public X509Certificate2 GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(Guid customerId)
{
    var distinguishedName = GetDistinguishedName(customerId);
    var rsa = RSA.Create(KeySize);
    var request = new CertificateRequest(distinguishedName, rsa, HashAlgorithm, Padding);
    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));
    request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(
        X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment |
        X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation, false));

    var cert = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(CertificateLifespan));
    return cert;
}
```

I then use this method to generate the cert and store it using the following method:

```
public void StoreCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
}
```

Next, I try to fetch the certificate from the certificate store using the following method:

```
public X509Certificate2 FetchPrivateCertificate(Guid customerId)
{
    var distinguishedName = GetDistinguishedName(customerId);
    using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, distinguishedName, false);
    store.Close();
    var privateCert = certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasPrivateKey);
    return privateCert;
}
```

...using the same `customerId`, this result is always null.  It's not even getting to check if the cert has a private key, the cert collection is always empty.  The distinguished name is generated exactly the same way.  The certificate is definitely in the cert store.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Per request, I'm adding how the Distinguished Name is generated:

```
private string GetDistinguishedName(Guid customerId)
{
    var domain = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    var domainDistinguishedName = string.Join(",DC=", domain.Split("."));
    var distinguishedName = $"DC={Environment.MachineName},DC={domainDistinguishedName},O={customerId}";

    return distinguishedName;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `distinguishedName` variable?

Comment: @Crypt32 it's a string.

Comment: Then string doesn't match the subject of formatted name of the certificate subject. Say, your `distinguishedName` may look as `CN=mysubject,O=example,C=us`, but formatted subject will be `CN=mysubject, O=example, C=us` (with spaces after RDN delimiter). It would be nice if you would provide an example of what is stored in variable and what name returns certificate.

Comment: @Crypt32 Ok I added it.  I see what you're talking about the spaces, let me see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Crypt32 yep that was it; certainly not obvious. If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as pointed in comments) is that your `GetDistinguishedName` returns unformatted x.500 string which is sufficient to build an X.500 name, but not sufficient for searching, because search function makes ordinal and case-insensitive comparison of input string and ***formatted*** X.500 string. That is, you can use these string formats to build the X.500 names:

```
CN=my common name,O=example LLC
CN = my common name,O = example LLC
CN= my common name, O =example LLC
<other variations>
```

CryptoAPI uses X.500 formatter to format any valid X.500 string to a consistent-looking string, e.g. capitalize RDN attribute names, remove spaces around `=` character, add space after RDN delimiter and even more, the function may re-order RDN attributes in the string. And when seraching for certs by X.500 name, you have to pass formatted/sanitized X.500 name to search function. The easiest way to do so is to update your `GetDistinguishedName` function as follows:

```
private string GetDistinguishedName(Guid customerId)
{
    var domain = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    var domainDistinguishedName = string.Join(",DC=", domain.Split("."));
    var distinguishedName = $"DC={Environment.MachineName},DC={domainDistinguishedName},O={customerId}";

    return new X500DistinguishedName(distinguishedName).Name;
}
```

i.e. force string formatting before returning it.

p.s. `DC={Environment.MachineName}` uses incorrect RDN attribute. DC stands for `domainComponent`. Machine name isn't a domain component by any mean. Use `CN` (common name) attribute to store machine name. And `O` stands for `Organization`. I suspect it is misused too, because `customerId` barely holds org name (just an assumption). You should use proper RDN types in subject/issuer strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: One thing to mention, the `ToString()` is not what to use, it should return the `Name` property.

Comment: That was a typo, posted at night. Thanks for notice, I've updated the answer.

Comment: A slightly better change would be to just return the `X500DistinguishedName` (and pass that to the CertificateRequest constructor) so that `CertificateRequest` doesn't have to then re-run the string processing.  Then use distinguishedName.Name in the call to Find.